# "No font found in Rcairo_set_font"

Tags: r, cairo

I have the following error while trying to use `Cairo`: `No font found in Rcairo_set_font`

Here is the log:

```
> library(Cairo)
> Cairo.capabilities()
   png   jpeg   tiff    pdf    svg     ps    x11    win raster
  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
> Cairo(600, 600, file="plot.png", type="png", bg="white")
Error in Cairo(600, 600, file = "plot.png", type = "png", bg = "white") :
  No font found in Rcairo_set_font
```

I'm using R version 3.2.1 on CentOS 7 (in a Docker container).

Does someone knows how I could avoid this error?

I didn't find anything on the web to fix this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix this by installing the `xorg-x11-fonts-Type1` package:

```
yum install xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
```